# сортировать словарь по ключам python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка

В словаре ключи это имена на английском, значения это цифры.
Нужно отсортировать словарь по ключам, чтобы начальные буквы имен
шли по алфавиту например словарь состоит из следующих ключей (имен) и их значений.

```
ivan 4
gena 101
sergey 100000
```

Должно получиться

```
gena 101
ivan 4
sergey 100000
```

Comment: Словарь - это неупорядоченная коллекция, его невозможно сортировать. Используйте [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: для вывода можно использовать `for key in sorted(dict.keys()): print(key, dict(key))`, но хранить в сортированном виде не получится как уже сказали выше

Comment: По-моему, начиная с Python 3.6 словари сохраняют порядок, т.е. ведут себя во многом как `OrderedDict`

Comment: @MaxU, на эту особенность не стоит полагаться. Не исключено, что в каком-нибудь Python 3.10 не придумают какую-то еще более быструю реализацию словаря, в котором данное свойство уже не будет выполняться.

Comment: @insolor, согласен, хотя конкретно от этой фичи трудно будет отказаться - [ее уже использует Python team](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0468/) ;)

Answer (score 0):

чтоб обратно вернул словарь уже отсортированный:

```
d = dict(sorted(d.items()))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
v=sorted(v.items())
for a,b in v:
    print (a, b)
```

Comment: или как правильно заметил slippyk   for key in sorted(dict.keys()): print(key, dict(key))  только скобки должны быть квадратные для вывода значений dict [ key ]  иначе будет ошибка

Comment: Для оформления кода есть кнопка `{}` в редакторе (выделить весь код и нажать кнопку). И все дополнения (тем более в виде кода) лучше вносить в сам ответ.